# "C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed" in a template function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

This code is so simple, shouldnt it compile? I am really lost with this one.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> foo(T f)
{
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp(6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a return type for `foo`. Presumably, you want:

```
                     vvvv
template<typename T> void foo(T f)
{                    ^^^^
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @TheVTM, Those templates will do that, just like how I keep thinking the 99 I have to prefix the phone number with at school is the area code and it takes me three tries to realize I'm missing three numbers.